# How can I include a third party library in my custom module without using Composer Manager

Tags: 8, composer

I'm trying to create a custom Twitter Pull module in Drupal 8.  I would like to include https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth.

I can't seem to get it working adding it via composer in the root composer.json file, or by using Composer Manager and creating a composer.json file in my module root, so for the sake of this question, how else can I include and make use of the library?

Can I add a dependency to my custom module .yml file?
How would I handle the namespacing/autoloading for this library in my custom module?

Comment: There is no other good way of including dependencies other than using composer manager (or the root composer.json manually by hacking core). Loading your own composer / vendor library is a recipe for disaster as you will probably soon double the size of your code base. I would focus on providing details or error messages when you use composer manager.

Comment: With the proper composer.json in a module, this works fine: see https://gist.github.com/mradcliffe/a4ff6219c39b1a26d472

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Going down the composer route (in either case, hacking root composer.json, or using Composer Manager, I can get library to download to the vendor directory, but I keep getting the class not found error with my "use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOauth"...  I was intrigued by the idea of possibly an alternate method, because I thought maybe I could keep that library in my custom module's folder, and maybe I could figure out the namespacing bit easier

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not able to reproduce an issue. I made a test module with a phpunit test that tests if oauth object is instance of `Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth`: https://github.com/mradcliffe/twitteroauth.

Comment: I'm not user if this is answer worthy because it would be really long and pretty specific. I think that there are some other questions/answers that go over Composer Manager specifically.

Comment: I just can't get it to work.  As a test I tried to create some objects from other libraries in the vendor directory.  I was able to create a guzzle object, and a masterminds/html5 using my same code / setup.  For whatever reason, I can't autoload the twitteroauth library, but it clearly lives in the vendor directory with all the others.

Comment: In my vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php file, I see the library and namespace listed. Is it listed there?

Comment: It is not! hmm...

Comment: Thank you mradcliffe... got it working!!  (runtime error crashing composer update, not finishing process, fixed that, autloload_psr4 updated as it shoud be.

Answer (score 1):

#### General: Composer Merge Plugin

In your Drupal's main `composer.json` you can use the [Composer Merge Plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) to scan certain directories for `composer.json` files and merge them into your main `composer.json`.

You'd then have a `composer.json` in your custom module requiring the 3rd party library. In your root `composer.json` you require the merge plugin and configure it under the `extra` section to include certain directories.

```
{
    "require": {
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master"
    },
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/custom/*/composer.json"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

#### Optional: Composer Custom Type Installer

If the 3rd party library in your custom module is available on GitHub and you want to define a location where the lib should to be downloaded to (extra helpful especially for all front-end libs) you can use [Composer Custom Type Installer](https://github.com/davidbarratt/custom-installer) in your main `composer.json`.

You'd then require the 3rd party library in the `repositories` section in your custom module's `composer.json` assigning it a package `type` you pre-configured in the `extra` section of your main `composer.json` to define a location where the lib should be downloaded to.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "select2",
            "version": "4.0.3",
            "type": "theme-library",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/select2/select2.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "tags/4.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And the corresponding `extra` section in the main `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "custom-installer": {
        "theme-library": "web/themes/custom/MYTHEME/libs/{$name}"
    }
}
```

---

Of course, for simplicity you could also do everything (`composer-merge-plugin` and `custom-installer` and requiring the GitHub repo) just from you main `composer.json`. I'd recommend that.

If you do so, then run at least once `composer require PACKAGENAME` (in my example `composer require select2`) after you manually incorporated the lib into the `composer.json` file.

---

Last but not least, don't forget to bind your library with `MYMODULE.libraries.yml` and `hook_page_attachments` (latter called from `MYMODULE.module`). See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module).